# Algorithm for two piles of equal heights by removing boxes at top or bottom

Tags: arrays, algorithm, subset-sum

Assume you have two piles, each made of `N` boxes of different heights. You want to remove boxes so as to obtain two piles of equal heights (if possible). You cannot remove a box which is not at the top or the bottom of the pile! One can see for instance that if we remove the red boxes below we obtain two towers of equal heights:

[image: example]

Another way to state this problem is: given two arrays of positive numbers, are there two consecutive sub-sequences (one in each array) whose sums are equal?

This problem looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608015/algorithm-to-find-a-consecutive-sub-sequence-whose-sum-would-be-a-asked-number-m), in which we have an array `A` of size `N` and a target `t`, and we want to find a consecutive sub-sequence of `A` whose sum is `t` (equivalently, we have a single pile of boxes and we want to remove boxes at the top and the bottom so as to obtain a pile of height `t`). This problem can be solved in time `O(N)`. On the other hand, the above-mentioned problem has a trivial `O(N^2)` solution (see the answers below), but is there also a `o(N^2)` algorithm (`O(N log N)` for instance)?

*Addendum*: The sizes of the boxes are positive integers. They are assumed to be all differents (otherwise the problem can be trivially solved in `O(N)`). If we denote by `H` the total size of the two piles, there is a `O(H log H)` algorithm (see the answers below). Thus, the problem starts to be interesting for `H` greater than `N` (an efficient solution for `H = N^2` would be a good start ;)

Comment: Can you explain why think this can solved in `O(n)`?

Comment: Is the sum of box heights limited?

Comment: hmm, I would be surprised by a O(n) solution. Something better than the naive O(n^3) would be nice.

Comment: O(n^2) is pretty straightforward (we can just add all different sums to a hash table)

Comment: It can also be done be in `O(H log H)`, where `H` is the sum of heights of boxes, which can be better if the sum of heights is limited by a reasonably small number.

Comment: yes, the true naive algorithm is O(n^2), I don't know why I said O(n^3)... So O(n) would be nice (but I can't explain why it could be possible)

Comment: I assume that the "remove all boxes, 0 = 0" solution is not allowed? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's find all the sums in `O(n^2)` and add them to a hash table:

```
for l in [0, n)
    cur_sum = 0
    for r in [l, n)
         cur_sum += a[r]
         hash_table.add(cur_sum)
```

After that, we need to do the same thing for the second array and check if at least one sum occurs in the hash table.

That's much better than a naive `O(n^3)` solution.

It's also possible to solve this problem in `O(H log H)` time, where `H` is the sum of boxes' heights if all heights are integers, but it's useful only if the total height is limited.

The `O(H log H)` solution goes like this:

We can find all subarray sums quickly. Let's take a look at what a subarray `S` sum is. It's a difference of two prefix sums `P[r] - P[l] = S`. If we add `H` to both sides of the equation, we obtain `P[r] + (H - P[l]) = H + S`. So we need to check if there exist two elements in the array `P[i]` and `H - P[i]`, respectively, that add up to a given value. Let's not just check their existence, but count the number of such pairs. No it looks exactly like a multiplication of two polynomials. The coefficients of the first polynomial are the number of occurrences of a specific prefix sum (`C[i] = count(j: P[j] == i)`). The second polynomial is essentially the same thing reversed. We can multiply these two polynomials in `O(H log H)` time using Fourier fast transform (as they both are of degree `H`). After that, we just need to check the `H + i` coefficient of the product is non-zero.

Once we know all sums for the first and the second array, we need to check if they have at least one in common.

Comment: Ok, so assume that the total height is around n^2 (to avoid the O(H log H) solution).

Comment: btw, can you explain the O(H log H) solution please

Comment: All the `P[i]`'s must be different (no box of zero height), so you don't need to define `C[i]`. The `H+i` coefficient will be the number of subarrays summing to `i`. Also, you should change `H - P[i]` to `H - P[j]`.

Comment: I believe your O(*H* log *H*) solution requires all of the boxes to have integer-valued heights. That's not an unreasonable assumption, but it's probably worth calling out explicitly.

Comment: @ruakh Yes, that's true.

Comment: The posted algorithm with two loops doesn't look correct as it doesn't take into account all possible sub-arrays denoted by `x`. For example, for 4 elements we've got 10 different sub-arrays as follows: `[x,-,-,-],[-,x-,-],[-,-,x,-],[-,-,-,x],[x,x,-,-],[-,x,x,-],[-,-,x,x],[x,x,x,-],[-,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x]`

Comment: @RZet: It looks right to me. What makes you say that it doesn't take into account all possible sub-arrays? (Of your ten different sub-arrays, which one(s) are you asserting it doesn't take into account?)

Comment: @ruakh Because it only takes into account only sums of the following sub-arrays: `[x,x,x,x],[-,x,x,x],[-,-,x,x],[-,-,-,x]` for `n=4`. Note the inner loop sums all the  elements ahead of the pointer of the outer loop.

Comment: @RZet: Not so. The inner loop takes a *running total* of elements, adding each *partial sum* to the hash-table. (Note the indentation.)

Comment: @ruakh Now agree, the psudo code confused me a bit.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds similar to the algorithm to find the length of the longest palindrome in a string.  In the palindrome algorithm, the beginning and end of the string is examined to determine if a palindrome exists, if not then the first character of the string is removed from the string so the rest of the string is compared with the result of taking off the last character of the string.

In this case, you are seeking a box that results from taking off the top and bottom of the pile.  If the pile doesn't result in a box of equal size in another pile, then take off the top of the pile and compare the result with taking the bottom of a pile.  The recursive pseudocode could look similar to:

```
global pile2
global HashTableForPile2  # each value is a box in Pile2
def FindBoxInPile(pile, top, bottom):
    if (top == ReachedBottomInPile or bottom == ReachedTopInPile):
        Stop processing and return False  ## base case
    else:
        # find the box created from the top to the bottom
        for i in range(bottom, top)
            sumPile1 += pile[i]
        # Determine if an identical box is inside both piles.  
        # If so, return True; otherwise, recurse.
        # (assuming HashTableForPile2 was calculated earlier)
        if (sumPile1 == HashTableForPile2[sumPile1]):  
            return True           

    # take top AND bottom off pile
    if (FindBoxInPile(pile1, top-1, bottom+1) == True):
        return True  # A box is inside both piles

    # take top OR bottom off pile and compare result
    elif (FindBoxInPile(pile1, top-1, bottom) == True or
          FindBoxInPile(pile1, top, bottom+1) == True)
        return True  # A box is inside both piles, return True
```

A dynamic programming solution would run in O(N) time.

Comment: I don't understand your pseudocode. What is supposed to return FindBoxInPile? True if the pile obtained from pile1 by removing the first "bottom" boxes and the last "top" boxes appears in pile2? And what is BoxInside? Why does it take a single parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear.  I modified the pseudocode to hopefully make it more clear.  My key point is to take the top and bottom off the pile.  If that doesn't result in a box in both piles then take either the top or the bottom off the pile and determine if that results in a box in both piles.  I hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You do recursive calls but I don't see where is the base case. Also I'm not sure we are talking about the same problem... We don't want to find two equal boxes (one in each pile), since usually the sizes of the 2N boxes are all different (ow the problem is too simple). Instead, we want to find two bunches of consecutives boxes (one bunch in each pile) that have the same total height.

Comment: By the way, great question!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, HashTableForPile2 contains all the possible sizes that can be obtained from pile2 by removing boxes at top and bottom. But this requires `O(N^2)` to be built since there are `O(N^2)` ways to remove boxes at top and bottom... And then you compute, one after the other, the sizes that can be obtained from pile1, and you check if they appear in HashTableForPile2. Once again, it requires `O(N^2)` in worst case...